# Ordering of Django models

Tags: python, django

I set up an `ordering='ordering_number'` Meta attribute to my Django model, thinking that Django will use it when comparing instances. (`ordering_number` is an IntegerField in my model.)

For example, if I have an instance `a` with `ordering_number = 4` and an instance `b` with `ordering_number = 7`, I'd expect that `a < b` would be `True`. However, I tested it, and it didn't seem to work. I did not understand according to which logic `a < b` would come out as `True`.

Does anyone know? Why doesn't Django uses `ordering` for element comparisons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering):

> The default ordering for the object, for use when obtaining lists of objects

So the reason your comparisons aren't working is because they're not designed that way. Define [`__lt__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) et alia to define ordering of instances.

Comment: Okay, I did and it works.

But wouldn't it be a good idea to do this automatically for all Django models?

Comment: File a RFE if you feel that passionately about this. http://code.djangoproject.com/

Comment: @cool-RR: Not it is not a good idea. *Default ordering* doesn't necessarily mean that two objects are also comparable that way. E.g. on SO the default ordering of the users is via name, but maybe a user is "larger" than another depending on his reputation. This is really a matter of context and just applying the default order also as natural order is a huge intervention into the business model imoh.